# Using “are” with “not able”

Tags: grammar

I came across these two sentences and can not explain the difference between them or if both are grammatically correct. What is the difference between these two sentences and which one is correct?

> So many young people arrive at university not able to look after themselves.
>
> So many young people arrive at university and are not able to look after themselves.

Comment: Where did you 'come across' the sentences? Are the two different versions intended to demonstrate a grammatical point? In the first one, _not able to look after themselves_ is a phrase describing the condition of the young people.

Comment: The first version is a [***complex*** sentence](https://www.oxfordsd.org/cms/lib/MS01001032/Centricity/Domain/641/sentences.pdf) (where ***not able to look after themselves*** adverbially modifies ***arrive***). The second is a ***compound*** sentence where ***So many young people arrive at university*** is combined with another statement: ***[those young people] are not able to look after themselves.*** I think most people would use ***unable*** rather than ***not able*** in adverbial contexts like the first example (but not necessarily the second).

Comment: The comments so far are relevant and helpful but your question might be better posed on the English Language Learners site.

Comment: Why do you think only one is correct?

Comment: Hmmm . . . both are fine, but it would be more idiomatic to replace "not able" with "unable".

Comment: "So many young people arrive at university and are not able to look after themselves" could technically be presenting two unrelated facts, but normally people would assume some connection, and infer that it means the same as the first sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatical.

I agree with the comment that “unable”” is more idiomatic with respect to the first sentence.

There are various ways to analyze the grammar of the first sentence. Perhaps the simplest is an ellipsis: [and are] is meant but implied rather than stated. More complex methods of analysis are possible. We could for example treat “not able to …” as an adjectival phrase modifying “young people” without mentioning ellipsis.

Comment: Yes.
In (i) then "not able to look..." should be treated as adverbial.
In (ii) you have "young people arrive..." and "young people are not able..." so it's actually an easier parse.